# Load header for data.frame from file

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two files. One file (`csv`) contains data, and second contains header for data (in one column). I need to unite both files and get `data.frame` with data from first file and header from second file. How it can be done?

---

Reduced sample. Data file:

```
10;21;36
7;56;543
7;7;7
7890;1;1
```

Header file:

```
height
weight
light
```

I need `data.frame` as from `csv` file:

```
height;weight;light
10;21;36
7;56;543
7;7;7
7890;1;1
```

Comment: Please show a reproducible example for testing.  If the second dataset is `df2` with header in a column say `col1`.  After reading the first data, use `colnames(df1) <-  as.character(df2$col1)`

Comment: read.csv("datafile.csv", col.names=readLines("headerfile"))

Comment: `read.table(file1, sep = ";", col.names = scan(file2, what = ""))`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `col.names` argument in `read.table()` to read the header file as the column names in the same call used to read the data file.

```
read.table(datafile, sep = ";", col.names = scan(headerfile, what = ""))
```

As @chinsoon12 shows in the comments, `readLines()` could also be used in place of `scan()`.

Answer (score 1):

We can read both the datasets with `header=FALSE` and change the column names with the first column of second dataset.

```
df1 <- read.csv("firstfile.csv", sep=";", header=FALSE) 
df2 <- read.csv("secondfile.csv", header=FALSE)
colnames(df1) <- as.character(df2[,1])
```